# Multiplying a generic type by two - binary tree method

Tags: java, generics, casting, tree, integer

I'm writing a method that doubles the size of the data in every node in a tree.  I think I have the algorithm down for writing it, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to multiply a generic type by 2.

So essentially I want to take a data that is type T and convert it to an integer, multiply it by two, and store it as type T.  I've played around with some options but none have worked.  Any help on how I should do this would be helpful.  If you need any other info let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: What knows how to do this conversion to integer?  Java doesn't just know how to arbitrarily intify an object other than via `hashCode`, and the results of doubling that wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you cannot do this directly. One approach is is to define a generic interface for objects that "know" how to double themselves:

```
public interface Doubler<T> {
    T doubled(T arg);
}
```

Then you can make each node (that knows how to double itself) implement the `Doubler` interface.

There are other approaches (factory methods, factory objects, passing around `Class<T>` instances, etc.) that might work just as well (or better). But the one thing you can't do is create an instance of a generic type in code that just knows the generic type and nothing else.

Comment: Also, what is `T`?  `T` doesn't extend `Doubler` so it's not doubling itself.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Good catch about the reserved word. `T` is the type parameter that OP described as being the data in each node. I was proposing as one approach that his generic node class could be declared with a type parameter `<T extends Doubler<T>` (or, perhaps better, `<T extends Doubler<? super T>>`).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your generic class / tree instance / generic method, don't leave generic type parameter T totally unconstrained, but make it a number (either a Long or a Double, depending on whether you need to handle integer or floating-point numbers:

**Instead of:**

```
public class DoubleTree<T> {
    private TreeSet<T> myTree;
    public void doubleTree() {
         // ...
         for (T treeElement: myTree) {
               // no way to double element because 
               // "minimum guaranteed base type of T" is Object!!
         } 
    }
}
```

**Try `T extends Long` as generic type param on first line:**

```
public class DoubleTree<T extends Long> {
    private TreeSet<T> myTree;
    public void doubleTree() {
         // ...
         for (T treeElement: myTree) {
               // Element has the Long interface - guaranteed
               T doubleIt = 2 * treeElement;

               // Note - you should really prevent numerical overflow in the above
               // e.g. if (treeElement < Long.MAX_VALUE / 2) {
               //            T doubleIt = 2 * treeElement; 
               //      } else { // Overflow error }
         } 
    }
}
```

For more generality, you could use "Number" instead of "Long".  But Number is an abstract type, that doesn't directly support multiplication by constants!  You work-around this by checking for the actual class at runtime via `instanceof` something like:

```
if (treeElement instanceof Long) {
      Long doubleIt = 2 * treeElement.longValue();
} else if (treeElement instanceof Integer) {
      Integer doubleIt = 2 * treeElement.intValue();
} else if (treeElement isntanceof Float) {
      Float doubleIt = 2.0 * treeElement.floatValue();
} // ..... etc
```